# Time elapsed of a bash script (days/minutes/seconds)

Tags: linux, bash, scripting, date, time

Infact when i want to have an estimated time it took when a script is finished.

```
startdate=$date

stuffs

enddate=$date
```

I wished to get the difference between these two dates and normally the script finishes less than 1 week. So i'll need it in number of days & minutes.

Comment: Have you tried using the `$SECONDS` variable that counts seconds since the script started?

Comment: Hi Kusalananda,

It works with the solution you provided below.

Answer (score 10):

From the `bash` manual:

> `SECONDS`
>
> Each time this parameter is referenced, the number of seconds
>          since shell invocation is returned.  If a value is assigned to
>          `SECONDS`, the value returned upon subsequent references is the
>          number of seconds since the assignment plus the value assigned.
>          If `SECONDS` is unset, it loses its special properties, even if it
>          is subsequently reset.

So whenever you want to time a piece of code with a timer that counts seconds, you may do

```bash
SECONDS=0

# code goes here

t=$SECONDS
```

To print days and minutes from the `$t` value:

```bash
printf 'Time taken: %d days, %d minutes\n' "$(( t/86400 ))" "$(( t/60 - 1440*(t/86400) ))"
```

Comment: Hi,
I confirm this one working. Many thanks

Comment: @KeshavBoodhun Good! You may want to look at
https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers, and also take the
tour: https://unix.stackexchange.com/tour (you'll receive a badge when
you've done so).

Answer (score 1):

Additionally: `time bash script.sh`

Comment: In fact I wanted to send the time taken by email after execution is finish. Though this command is useful too.

Answer (score 0):

You can use timestamps with `date "+%s"`

```
$ date "+%s"
1590502845
```

And use bash `$(())` for the calculation

```bsh
START=$(date "+%s")

work ... work... work ...

END=$(date "+%s")

echo $((END-START))
```

Comment: Without calling `date` in `bash` 4.2+: `printf -v START '%(%s)T' -1`

Answer (score 0):

What's missing from most answers, is a simple way to get the time in terms of `hh:mm:ss` format.

Let's keep things simple, and use Bash built-ins only:

```bash
# Using the Bash built-in SECONDS
SECONDS=0;sleep 0; t=$((SECONDS+241));TT=$(date -u -d "@${t}" +%T); printf 'Time taken: %s\n' "$TT"
# Time taken: 00:04:01

# Using date differences, and give result in hh:mm:ss
S=$(date -u +"%s"); E=$((S+121)); TT=$((E-S)); date -u -d "@${TT}" +%T
# 00:02:01
```