# How to save execution time of a script to variable while printing script's stdout to console?

Tags: bash, shell, time

I would like to measure time spent on a script and save it to a variable. This is my current code:

```
time_spent=$(time ./script.sh)
...
echo $time_spent
```

Here is how it should work:
The script output should go into the console immediately since the script may need user interaction. The time spent should be saved to a variable for later use.

Can this be done with `time` or should I use something else?

Comment: You could consider using the bash shell's built in `SECONDS` variable - see for example [Time elapsed of a bash script (days/minutes/seconds)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/589067/time-elapsed-of-a-bash-script-days-minutes-seconds)

Comment: I would like to measure time with more precision, like the `time` command does

Comment: You're probably not going to be able to use the output of bash's `time`. It's a shell built in and doesn't conform to normal redirection and capture of stdin and stdout. You should consider a wrapper script that grabs a timestamp from `date` before and after the script runs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/usr/bin/time` rather than the time builtin can write the times to a file with the `-o` option.

```
$ /usr/bin/time -p -o times sleep 1
$ cat times
real 1.01
user 0.00
sys 0.00
```

See the man page for more info.